# How would I remove this empty space in a shopify order confirmation email?

Tags: html, css, email, shopify, liquid

[image: Image To Show The Empty Space In The Email]

Here is my code: https://pastebin.com/tZGifcPj

What I Am Trying To Make It Look Like: [image: Here]

I have tried to look in the code but I don't see any thing that I think would make the empty space. I've only managed to remove it by using inspect element on the email and have tried to find the code that I remove using inspect element  (please keep in mind that I am an amateur in programming)

`<p> hello world </p>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try and remove the `<td class="subtotal-spacer"></td>` on **line 265**, that might remove the space that pushes the totals to the right side.